# Bounding the decrease after applying a contraction operator $n$ vs $n+1$ times

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra

Can we upper bound the convergence rate of
$$\max_{\textbf{v}: \left\Vert \textbf{v}\right\Vert_2=1} \left\{ \left\Vert \textbf{T}^n \textbf{v}\right\Vert^2_2 - \left\Vert \textbf{T}^{n+1} \textbf{v}\right\Vert^2_2 \right\}~,$$
where $\textbf{T}\in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$  is a contraction operator
($\left\Vert\textbf{T}\right\Vert_2\le1$)
of rank $r<d$?

---

For example, $\textbf{T}$ can be *nilpotent* with index $q$ (e.g., $\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$) and then the maximal decrease *can* be fixed as long as $n<q$, and afterwards it is $0$.

---

I found a Toeplitz operator whose rate is $d/en$:
$$\boldsymbol{T}=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
 & 1\\
 &  & \ddots\\
 &  &  & 1\\
1-\epsilon
\end{array}\right]$$ and I have an intuition this should be the upper bound, but I was not able to prove that this is indeed the worst case.

Comment: I'll just say it's a simplification of another question I asked a few days ago which probably was too complicated. In essence, it's related to alternating projections but still different because, e.g., eigenvalues of $1$ do not make the objective here stay stuck on $1$.

Comment: Contraction means $\|T\|<1$? Which type of result do you need?

Comment: Added a clarification that I mean that the spectral norm <= 1. An example of a result that can be helpful is an upper bound of $r/n$.

Comment: you may get some bad but by explicit bound $c(r,n)$, where $c(r,n)$ goes to 0 for fixed $r$ and $n$ going to infinity as follows: by pigeonhole principle there exist $a<b\leqslant n+1$ for which $T^a v$ and $T^b v$ are close, then $T^{n+1}v$ is close to $T^{n+1-(b-a)}v$ and apply $\|T^{n+1-(b-a)}v\|\leqslant \|T^nv\|\leqslant \|T^{n+1}v\|$.

Comment: sorry, both inequalities must be $\geqslant$ of course

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131431/discussion-between-itay-and-fedor-petrov).

Comment: I don't think that your result for nilpotent operators holds. For instance, $T = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1/2\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ is index-2 nilpotent, but the maximal decrease for $n=1$ is $1/2$, not $1$. Or do you want a maximum over all possible operators $T$ as well?

Comment: Yes you are correct, the scale of the matrix matter. What I meant is that it *can* be $1$ (or fixed) until it becomes zero. And yes, I am looking for a non-trivial bound that is true for any $T$.

Comment: Any orthogonal operator $T$ has norm $\|T\|_2=1$, and the quantity in the second line independent of $n$

Comment: Please notice that I require $rank<d$

Comment: Also @PietroMajer, even in your example, the objective would be $0$, so it is still bound.

Comment: (As to k<r: then an orthogonal projector with v in its image).

Comment: Agreed, and it's still bounded :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily get a slightly cruder bound $d/n$ (or, if you want, $r/n$) as follows.

Let $A_n=(T^*)^nT^n$ and $B_n=A_n-A_{n+1}$. Then $(B_nv,v)=\|T^nv\|^2-\|T^{n+1}v\|^2\ge 0$, so $B_n$ is positive definite. Also $B_{n+1}=T^*B_nT$, so, since $T$ is a contraction, $Tr B_{n+1}\le Tr B_n$ (this is obvious if $T$ is diagonal but in general $T=R_1DR_2$ where $R_j$ are orthogonal and $D$ is a diagonal contraction and conjugation by an orthogonal matrix doesn't change either trace, or positive definiteness).

So, $n\, Tr B_n\le \sum_{k=1}^n Tr B_k=Tr A_1-Tr A_{n+1}\le Tr A_1\le r$ and we are done because the trace dominates the norm for positive definite matrices.

Comment: Wow! That is a very clean proof. Thank you.